# sphinx - several files in a chapter and clean html-navigation with rtd-theme possible?

Tags: python, navigation, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm using sphinx 1.3.4¹ to write my documentation, `make html` uses the „read the docs“ theme².

When I include a file chaper1.rst in index.rst with headings from Lv 1 to Lv3 in this document, I see
 heading lv 1 in my resulting navigation-sidebar. After clicking this Heading,
 It collapses and shows heading lv2 -lv3. **Fine**, that`s ok.

When I split my chapter1 in several files, I can use `chaper1/*` in index.rst and in my
resulting html-documentation every file is included. **BUT** each files heading
- also those with beginning lv2 - shows in the central navigation-sidebar
collapse as separate chapter. No collapsing chapter headings anymore. :-/

How can I use several files for each chapter *and* achive a clean navigation on the left side?

**tia!**

*Edit*
I did a backport of rtd-theme Version 0.1.9 - no change. So it seems to be  a sphinx problem. **How do I proper include several files to one chapter?**

[1] https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/python3-sphinx
[2] https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3-sphinx-rtd-theme

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I have to write a heading before `.. toctree::`  so sphinx knows how to arrange the following files and headings…